# Excel: Need to count occurrences that values in column are greater than another column AND value in a third column is specified

Tags: excel, countif, sumifs

The dummy data below is similar to the data I'm working with. I want to check how many instances that the value is greater than the goal, only in one region at a time.

To clarify, I have already figured out how to count the number of occurrences in which values in one column are greater than corresponding values in another row as follows:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A>B:B))`

or (as an array formula):

`=SUM(IF(A:A>B:B,1,0))`

I have another column specifying different regions in the country. I want to count these same occurrences for individual regions. For example, when the region is "Southeast". I have tried adding an & statement within these previous formulas, as well as multiple `sumifs`, `countifs`, and various variations of all of the above. I am continuously either getting a 0 or an error as my answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post screenshots of your data

Comment: smells like database functions are your go to...

Comment: Instead of a picture, can you post the table as data? That helps us copy/paste into Excel to help you out quicker.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(C:C>B:B)*(A:A="Southeast"))`
C is the column of Values
B is the column of Goals
A is the column of Region